How to Query User Access Logs for Azure Front Door
I am trying to analyze user activity through Azure Front Door by querying logs in Azure Log Analytics.
I want to find out how many users accessed a particular domain (www.disforum.com) in the last 90 days from Microsoft Azure Front Door.
However, I'm unsure if the AzureDiagnostics table has the right fields for Front Door domain user access logs.
Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

What is a user in your case? A unique IP address? Since AFD does not inspect token and such it does not know anything about your concept of a user. You are probably better of logging useage in your application.

User, I mean the IP address. I'm trying to determine how many  IPs are accessing a particular domain each month.

If you want a simple count of the number of distinct IPs that have hit your Front Door instance in the past 30 days this KQL query would work:
AzureDiagnostics
| where TimeGenerated > ago(30d) and Category == "FrontDoorAccessLog"
| summarize UniqueEvents=count_distinct(clientIp_s) 

The "clientIp_s" column is from the FrontDoorAccessLog category, the "clientIP_s" is from the FrontDoorWebApplicationFirewallLog.
You can get to the Log Analytics workspace associated to your Front Door by clicking on the "Logs" blade from within Front Door, under the "Monitoring" category:

